# PostgreSQL JDBC - relation already exists when creating table using PreparedStatements

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

So I am creating a JDBC program using a connection. This is my first time becoming familiar with this kind of programming so please excuse me if my question comes across as "dumb". But I have been stuck on this issue for a while. I am created 4 new tables. It compiles fine but when I run it, I get a "ERROR: relation "joke" already exists". When I remove the createTableJoke prepared statement, I get the same error ("ERROR: relation "gift" already exists") for my gift table. This continues for all my statements. What am I doing wrong and what is the logic behind why PostgreSQL does this? I have included my code below:

```
private static void createTables() throws SQLException {

PreparedStatement createTableJoke = null;
PreparedStatement createTableGift = null; 
PreparedStatement createTableHat = null;
PreparedStatement createTableCracker = null;
Connection conn = null; 
try {
    conn = getDBConnection();
    createTableJoke = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE Joke ( jid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, joke CHAR(200) NOT NULL, royalty FLOAT NOT NULL);");
    createTableJoke.executeUpdate();
    createTableGift = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE Gift ( gid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description CHAR(100) NOT NULL, price FLOAT NOT NULL);");
    createTableGift.executeUpdate();
    createTableHat = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE Hat ( hid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description CHAR(100) NOT NULL, price FLOAT NOT NULL);");
    createTableHat.executeUpdate();
    createTableCracker = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE Cracker (cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name CHAR(20) NOT NULL, jid INTEGER REFERENCES Joke(jid), gid INTEGER REFERENCES Gift(gid), hid INTEGER REFERENCES Hat(hid), saleprice NUMERIC CHECK (saleprice > 0), quantity INTEGER NOT NULL);");
    createTableCracker.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    if ((createTableJoke != null) && (createTableGift != null) && (createTableHat != null) && (createTableCracker != null)){
        createTableJoke.close();
        createTableGift.close();
        createTableHat.close();
        createTableCracker.close();
    } 
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which part of "already exists" confuses you? You have apparently already run the program once without error, so now the tables exist in the database. What would be the point of a database if it doesn't retain what you've created?

Comment: *Curious:* Why are you using `PreparedStatement` to execute DDL statements? Use a `Statement` instead, and reuse it for all 4 `executeUpdate` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. You don't care about keeping the existing table if there is one. In this case, issue "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Joke" before creating it. This will ensure the table is deleted, it will not fail when the table is not there.
2. You care about the existing content of your tables. In this case, issue a "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Joke" ... instead of your plain CREATE TABLE. This will ensure the table is there, and if it already exists, it will not be created. Also note, if you change the structure in your create statement and the table exists, the change in structure does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors means, that all this table were already created. Use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) (on Microsoft Windows operating systems it usually goes along with PostgreSQL installation) or psql client to connect to the database and check table existence.